# R: Importar mapas formato shapefile a R

Tags: r

Con estos paquetes:

```
        library(readr)
        library(leaflet)
        library(magrittr)
        library(ggmap)
        library(ggrepel)
```

Me gustaría poder poner estos putos en un mapa con mayor relieve siguiendo este script

```
        puntos <- data.frame(lon=c(-3.391830, -3.530613, -3.205903, -3.137145, -3.500323,-3.536191, -3.196057,  -3.131139,  -3.345220, -3.476462,   -3.125794,  -3.252617,  -3.345220,  -3.503040,  -3.125000,  -3.182801,  -3.476076,  -3.131000,  -3.593308,  -3.599064,  -3.477574,  -3.214026,  -3.253943),
                  lat=c(39.595520, 40.225155, 40.320294, 40.345348, 40.059138,  40.234966,  40.089637,  40.494167,  40.03184,   40.048758,  40.050352,  40.245459,  40.03184,   40.050578,  40.0459,    40.032298,  40.050052,  40.04472,   40.051302,  40.043193,  40.04933,   40.085899,  40.245852),
                  nom=c('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4','E1', 'E2', 'E3', 'E4',
                       'L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4','M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4',
                      'Z1', 'Z2','C1', 'C2', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3'),
                 habitat=c('Oak', 'Oak', 'Oak', 'Oak','Wasteland', 'Wasteland', 'Wasteland', 'Wasteland',
                       'Edge', 'Edge', 'Edge', 'Edge','Crop', 'Crop', 'Crop', 'Crop',
                       'Crop', 'Crop','Crop', 'Crop', 'Crop', 'Crop', 'Crop'))

        puntos<-as.data.frame(puntos)

        map.unizar <- get_map( location = c(-3.4, 40.1),
                   color = "color",
                   maptype = "terrain",
                   scale = 2,
                   zoom = 9)

        ggmap(map.unizar) + geom_point(aes(color=habitat),
                           data = puntos,
                           size = 2)                                                                                                                                                                    

         +scale_x_continuous("longitude")+scale_y_continuous("latitude")+
           geom_text_repel(aes(label = puntos$nom),
                          data = puntos, 
                          size = 3, 
                          #vjust = 0.75, 
                          #hjust = -0.3,
                          color = "black")
```

Por lo que mi pregunta sería ¿Cómo puedo importar un mapa en formato shapefile en R para hacerle el mismo tratamiento del script que he resumido antes?
Este es el shapefile:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H7mxuGJq_qAZUB2xHG4FShisf7ccSvKN/view

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Adrian, el enlace direcciona a una búsqueda algo compleja, te sugiero que compartas directamente el mapa ya descargado al que quieres agregarle las referencias,  es shapefile? una imágen?

Comment: es formato shapefile, ¿Cómo lo adjunto?

Comment: aunque también puedo descargarmelo en formato pdf dándole al botón imprimir que sale en el link que adjunté

Comment: Yo lo compartiría mediante un dropbox, google drive o algo similar que tengas. El tema de un PDF o un shapefile es que las soluciones son totalmente distintas, Creo que un shapefile es más flexible que un PDF. Saludos.

Comment: Cierto, no había pensado en google drive, este es el enlace del shapefile https://drive.google.com/open?id=1H7mxuGJq_qAZUB2xHG4FShisf7ccSvKN y este del pdf https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RmBQSjuYB8Dy_qHEcu48WKZunoqWLTHw

Comment: Adrian, un shapefile, básicamente es una lista de puntos, lineas o polígonos, estos objetos pueden representar calles, vías de tren, construcciones, cualquier cosa. El del enlace es concretamente un mapa de ocupación del  territorio, lo he leído en R pero no es más que una máscara para indicar la ocupación de la tierra, no veo que te sirva para lo que buscas.

Comment: En la respuesta que puse comento eso mismo. Básicamente te paso el código para levantar en R es shapefile, pero voy más allá porque no queda claro que es lo que querés hacer con esa capa.

Comment: @mpaladino creo que lo que busca Adrian más bien es una imagen tipo "Terrain" o satelital y sobre eso poder establecer los marcadores, veamos que opina. Muy buenas tus notas.

Comment: perdonar, he estado muy ocupado durante esta semana, sencillamente quiero eso, conseguir imagen tipo "Terrain" y sobre la misma establecer los puntos. Esta imagen la quería tomar de la página web que puse al principio donde me descargué el archivo en formato shapefile. Muchas gracias por todas las respuestas que me habeis dado, y disculpar de nuevo por la demora de tiempo de respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el primer paso sería importar el shapefile, convirtiéndolo en el camino en un objeto de la clase `SPDF` (Spatial Polygon DataFrame). Esta es una clase especial de objetos de R que se usa para manejar polígonos cartográficos. Para poder usarlos deberías tener instaladas las librerías `sp`, `rgdal` y `rgeos`. Tienen dependencias entre sí, en general R las resuelve. Dependiendo del sistema operativo que estés usando podrías tener alguna complicación, porque hay dependencias a nivel sistema operativo que R no puede resolver. En mi experiencia es relativamente fácil en Windows y da algo más de guerra en Linux (Fedora) y macOS. Tampoco es imposible.

Con los paquetes instalados y funcionando tenés que tener **todo** el contenido del .zip con los shapefiles en una carpeta, no sólo el archivo .shp. La proyección y otros metadatos están en archivos separados. Todos tienen que tener el mismo nombre y cambiar solamente la extensión, en tu caso los datos ya están bien en este sentido.

Idealmente los ubicas en una subcarpeta del proyecto de R en el que estás trabajando, para poder trabajar con path relativos. En este caso uso `./CORINE`.

Con esto listo pasas a importar los shapes a un objeto `SPDF` con la función `readOGR` de `rgdal`.

```
library(rgdal)
readOGR("./CORINE") -> poligonos   #Importo los polígonos
#readOGR me pasa una advertencia señalando que ignoró la dimensión Z. Asumo que no cargó los relieves, no sé cuan problemático es eso para tus propósitos. 
plot(poligonos)                    #Mapa básico, para ver si todo anda bien. Hay un método plot para objetos SPDF.
```

Hasta aquí con la importación de los datos. El resto de la pregunta no la entiendo bien, es decir, no sé si querés agregar la capa de CORINE sobre un mapa de google maps (el que se obtiene con ggmap en el script de ejemplo) o poner los puntos de `puntos` sobre el mapa de CORINE.

## Nota sobre los datos.

Me parece que hay un problema con los datos importados de CORINE, las latitudes y longitudes que resultan son muy raras (el Cantábrico anda por el paralelo 4800000). Puede que estén usando un sistema de coordenadas no convencional (pasa por ejemplo con INEGI en México, usan una proyección propia que expresa las coordenadas en metros y no grados y el cero lo definen con un datum propio). Te sugiero revisar con cuidado los documentos técnicos de la organización que produce esos shapefiles. Si es como creo que es va a estar complicado unir las diferentes capas, porque tendrías que hacer una "traducción" para homologar los sistemas de coordenadas.

Un cuaderno de notas sobre ese problema y de paso algunos ejemplos básicos de cartografía en R está en https://martinpaladino.github.io/Mapas_con_R.html Es una guía que preparé hace algún tiempo para mis alumnos.